# Перестает работать кнопка из-за js

Tags: php, javascript, html

Здравствуйте, имеется страница с товаром на котором есть кнопка "Добавить в корзину", всё работает отлично, при нажатии товар добавляется в корзину. Мне необходимо добавить было в js 2 скрипта:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/theme.js"></script>
```

После того как я добавил их, перестала корректно работать кнопка "Добавить в корзину". То есть при нажатии товар перестал добавляться в корзину и соответственно в бд. При нажатии на кнопку просто обновляется страница. Как только отключаю этих 2-скрипта всё работает как часы. Так вот, какие файлы мне необходимо предоставить для показа? Заранее всем благодарю за внимание и прошу прощения если не корректно создал тему.

Comment: А что консоль показывает?

Comment: @newProgrammer просто зайти на страницу и сделать скриншот консоли или при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: Вроде показывает консоль это:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jCarouselLite is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (shop-script.js:3)
    at k (jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.D (jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)

Comment: попробовали, использовать другую версию `jquery`?

Comment: @newProgrammer нет, сейчас попробую. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно скачать актуальную версию?

Comment: Вам нужно добавить в страницу jquery.jcarousellite.js -  http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/demo.php

Comment: @Igor точно? просто если я не подключаю эти 2 js то консоль не ругается

Comment: jCarouselLite is not a function

Comment: Удалил js с каруселью, в консоли пишет:
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jCarouselLite is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (shop-script.js:3)
    at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)

Comment: "Удалил js с каруселью" - значит не удалили

Comment: @Igor удалил, уверен... Да и к тому же, почему когда я не подключаю те 2 js то ошибок нету?

Comment: Но Вы же видите, что у Вас в странице есть попытка выполнить `$(...).jCarouselLite(...)`. Откуда этот код?

Comment: @Igor я без понятия... Но  удалил js с каруселью... Могли бы оставить свои данные?